# Get element of tuple in list

Tags: haskell

How do I access an element of a tuple in a list?

For example

```
func :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int
func (x:xs) --here I want to access c of every tuple (a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a simple function to access the third element of a tuple then just use `map`

```
thrd :: (a, b, c) -> c
thrd (a, b, c) = c

func :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [Int]
func xs = map thrd xs
```

That will give you a list containing the third element of each tuple.  I don't know what you want to do to it to convert it to a single `Int`, though.  Could you elaborate on your use case?

---

To get the average of these elements you're going to have to do some conversion.  You can't divide `Int`s, because `Int` is not an instance of the `Fractional` type class which defines `(/)`.  You could write an average function like

```
average :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
average xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

But this would mean you would have to convert every single element coming out of `map thrd xs` into a `Fractional`.  It'd be much more efficient to make a specialized averaging function for the `Int` type defined as

```
averageInt :: Fractional a => [Int] -> a
averageInt xs = fromIntegral (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

The difference here is that you sum the list first, then convert that result to a `Fractional`.  You have to perform the sum either way, but this reduces the number of conversion you have to do from the number of elements in your list to 1 no matter the size of the list.

You can then use it as

```
averageThrd :: Fractional a => [(Int, Int, Int)] -> a
averageThrd xs = averageInt $ map thrd xs
```

Since `Float` and `Double` are both instances of `Fractional`, you can convert to either of these types on demand with some in-line type annotations:

```
> averageThrd [(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3)] :: Double
2.0
> averageThrd [(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3)] :: Float
2.0
```

Comment: In this case, I would like to sum the elements, then divide by the number of elements to get an average.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can simply nest pattern matches:

```
func :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int
func ((a, b, c) : xs) = ... -- do something with c, and probably recurse on xs
func []               = ... -- don't forget the base case
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be stuck with conversions. Average with an `Int` is inherently messy if you use the wrong averaging. You need the `fromIntegral` command to convert your Int to a float-type number like so ...

```
f x = sAll / l
    where
        f3 (_,_,x) = x 
        sAll       = sum $ map (fromIntegral . f3) x 
        l          = fromIntegral $ length x 

{- 
[prompt] f [(1,2,3), (2,4,6)]
4.5
[prompt] 
-}
```

Was this the problem?